# Picasso image not loaded

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my code in Picasso. XML layout have only Image View. But the output shows just a blank screen. I don't know why the image is not appearing on the screen?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.hassidiczaddic.happycoding;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ImageView imageview1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        String imageUrl = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/
   icons/angry-icons-by-femfoyou/512/whitebird.png"

        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this).listener(new Picasso.Listener(){
            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso,Uri uri,Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).build();
        picasso.load(imageUrl).into(imageview1, new Callback(){
            public  void onSuccess(){
                Log.d(TAG, "succcess");
            }
            public void onError(){
                Log.d(TAG,"ERROR");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: internet permission?

Comment: yes i have added it on android Manifest.

Comment: you image link is broken i think.

Comment: yes. I have also to the link

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code and inspect the properties to see their values.

Comment: i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png This link also does not shows anything.

Answer (score 4):

open the link on browser..
your link is response 404 error

also put default image (error())

```
        Picasso.with(context)
            .load(imageURL)
            .error(R.drawable.default).into(imageView);
```

Comment: It shows nothing even if i use this link.                                                                     http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png

Comment: try this please:  
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616076655547682816/6gMRtQyY.jpg

your path is wrong because is open the web and not direct the image

Answer (score 4):

This code works for me :

```
String imageUrl = "i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png";

Picasso.with(this)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .fit()
    .centerInside()
    .into(imageview1, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.d(TAG, "succcess");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            Log.d(TAG, "error");
        }
    }
);
```

And change "wrap_content" of your ImageView to "match_parent"

Comment: Thank you for this solution  but why it takes a time to load?